# How do I add an ActioListener to a JFileChooser in MVC

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I currently have a `JFileChooser` in my view class, which I want to trigger certain events stored in my controller class. I add `ActionListeners` to `JButtons` like the following:

```
view.setUploadButtonListener(new UploadButtonListener());
```

where `view` is my view class and `UploadButtonListener` is an internal class of my controller class. The same way doesn't seem to work for `JFileChooser` (at least I can't figure it out).

How can I add an `ActionListener` to my `JFileChooser` that fires when the user clicks **OK**. And can I pass the selected file path as argument in the listener as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your view logic in view and controller logic in controller I would go for something like that:

```
class UploadButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    private View view;
    public UploadButtonListener(View view){
        this.view = view;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String filename = view.getFileName();
        if(!filename.isEmpty()){
                    ... your logic
            }
    }

}
```

then add to your view class following method:

```
public String getFileName(){
   JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
   if (fc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
     return fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
   else
     return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works so far. Could you explain me what the `AddCheckBoxAction` is triggered by? I am confused by the name as there are no checkboxes in my gui.

Comment: Sorry for confusion I was doing copy paste from my older project and I forgot to change the name of constructor :) I renamed it to UploadButtonListener now. It is a constructor of course and in your View class you can simply do the following:
JButton btn = new JButton("btn");
btn.addActionListener( new UploadButtonListener(this) );
or 
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Upload File");
menuItem.addActionListener( new UploadButtonListener(this) );
Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3390237/230513), you can use the chooser's `addActionListener()` method. The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3390237/230513) implements several listeners, including `ActionListener`. For additional flexibility consider substituting a suitable [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend: "[How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)"

`JFileCooser` `showOpenDialog` method pops up an `Open File` file chooser dialog and returns value of the state of the file chooser on popdown:

- `JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION`
- `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`
- `JFileCHooser.ERROR_OPTION`

So this is the code for your `ActionListener` that will open `File Chooser` and react on demand:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (fc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String name = file.getName();
        ...
    }
}
```

Read more about `showOpenDialog` here: [showOpenDialog - doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog%28java.awt.Component%29)

Comment: +1 for tutorial link. Can you provide a more recent API link?

Comment: Thanks for your help. First Time i posted something here and surprised how fast i got an answer.